# String parsing in C... strtok() doesn't quite get it done

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

OK... first question so please forgive me if it isn't quite understandable the first go.

I am attempting to parse a string input to stdin through a couple of different conditions.
Example input string: `move this into "tokens that I need" \n`

I would like to parse this into tokens as:

Token 1 = `move`

Token 2 = `this`

Token 3 = `into`

Token 4 = `tokens that I need`

Where the tokens are by whitespace (easy enough) until a quote is encountered, then everything inside of the open and close quotes is treated as a single token.

I've tried several different methods, but I unfortunately feel that I may be in over my head here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My latest attempt:

```
    fgets(input, BUFLEN, stdin); //gets the input
    input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';//removes the new line

    printf("Input string = %s\n",input);//Just prints it out for me to see

    char *token = strtok(input,delim);//Tokenizes the input, which unfortunately does not do what I need.  delim is just my string of delimiters which currently only has a " " in it.
```

I tried to scan through the string one character at a time and then place those characters into arrays so that I could have them as I wanted, but that failed miserably.

Comment: What is `delim`?

Comment: delim is my string of delimiting characters... currently only has " " inside of it.

Comment: Add that to your answer

Comment: I added it to my question

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate solution with customized version of `my_strtok_r` is here. This solution has advantage over solution with non re-entrant: `strtok`.

`my_strtok_r` is re-entrant: you can call them from multiple threads simultaneously, or in nested loops, et cetera.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * my_strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim1, const char *delim2, char **save_ptr)
{
    char *end;
    size_t s1;
    size_t s2;
    int delim2found = 0;

    if (s == NULL)
        s = *save_ptr;

    if (*s == '\0'){
        *save_ptr = s;
        return NULL;
    }

    s1 = strspn (s, delim1);
    s2 = strspn (s, delim2);

    if(s2 > s1){
        s += s2;
        delim2found  = 1;
    }
    else{
        s += s1;
    }

    if (*s == '\0'){
        *save_ptr = s;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Find the end of the token.  */
    if(delim2found)
        end = s + strcspn (s, delim2);
    else
        end = s + strcspn (s, delim1);

    if (*end == '\0') {
        *save_ptr = end;
        return s;
    }

    /* Terminate the token and make *save_ptr point past it. */
    *end = '\0';
    *save_ptr = end + 1;
    return s;
}

int main (void)
{
    char str[] = "   123 abc \"SPLITTING  WORKS\"  yes! \"GREAT WE HAVE A SOLUTION\"  !    ";
    char *d1 = " ";
    char *d2 = "\"";
    char *token;
    char *rest = str;
    char array[20][80];

    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);

    size_t nr_of_tokens = 0;
    while ((token = my_strtok_r(rest, d1, d2, &rest)))
    {
        strcpy (array[nr_of_tokens], token);
        nr_of_tokens++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < nr_of_tokens; i++)
        printf ("%s\n",array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Splitting string "   123 abc "SPLITING  WORKS"  yes! "GREAT WE HAVE A SOLUTION"  !    " into tokens:                                           
123                                                                                                                                            
abc                                                                                                                                            
SPLITTING  WORKS                                                                                                                                
yes!                                                                                                                                           
GREAT WE HAVE A SOLUTION                                                                                                                       
!
```

This is another solution (fully tested) which you can use. You can mix any number of tokens delimited by white spaces and `'\"'`. It can be configured to your needs. Extensive explanations are given in the code itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *get_str_segment(char *output_str, char *input_str, char extDel)
{
    /*
     Purpose :

        To copy to output first segment.

        To extract the segment two types of delimiters are used:
            1. white space delimiter
            2. 'extDel' -
                 do not put here white space or '\0'!
                 (typicaly '"'  = quote!)

        'extDel' allows us to put white spaces inside the segment.
        Notice that 'extDel' cannot be embedded inside the segment!
        It makes 'extDel' special character which will not be encountered
        in the 'output_string'! First appearance of 'extDel' starts new
        segment!
        Notice that unbalanced 'extDel' will cause coping whole string to
        destination from that point!

        Return:

        Pointer to the first character after the segment
        or NULL !!!

        we will not allow **empty** segments with unbalanced 'extDel'
        if ('extDel' is unbalanced) it has to have at list one character!
        It can be white space!


        Notice!
        "get_str_segment()" on strings filed with white spaces
         and empty strings will return *** NULL *** to indicate that
         no conclusive segment has been found!


        Example:
        input_str  =    "  qwerty"123 45"  "samuel" G7 "
        output_str = ""

        //  Call:  
        char *ptr = get_str_segment(output_str,input_str,'"');

        Result:

        input_str  =    "  qwerty"123 45"  "samuel" G7 "

                                 ^
                                 |
        ptr----------------------.

        output_str =    "qwerty"
    */

    char *s  = input_str;
    char *d  = output_str;
    char  i  = 0;


    if(!s) return NULL; // rule #1 our code never brakes!
    if(!d) return NULL;

    // eliminate white spaces from front of the block

    while(1)
    {
        if ( *s == '\0')
        {
            *d = '\0' ;       // end the output string
            return (NULL) ;   // return NULL to indicate that no
            // coping has been done.
            //
            //
            // "get_str_segment()" on
            // strings filed with white spaces
            // and empty strings
            // will return NULL to indicate that
            // no conclusive segment has been found
            //
        }

        if (isspace(*s)) ++s;  // move pointer to next char
        else break;            // break the loop!
    }

    // we found first non white character!

    if( *s != extDel)
    {
        // copy block up to end of string first white space or extDel

        while( ((*s) != '\0') && (!isspace(*s)) && ((*s) != extDel) )
        {
            *d = *s;        // copy segment characters
            ++s;
            ++d;
        }

        *d = '\0' ;  // end the destination string
        return (s);  // return pointer to end of the string  ||
        // trailing white space ||
        // 'extDel' char
    }
    else // It is 'extDel' character !
    {
        ++s; // skip opening 'extDel'

        while( ((*s) != '\0') && ((*s) != extDel) )
        {
            i=1;            // we executed loop at list one time

            *d = *s;        // copy segment characters till '\0' or extDel
            ++s;
            ++d;
        }

        *d = '\0' ;  // end the destination string

        if( *s == extDel ) ++s;  // skip *closing* 'extDel'
        else
        {
            // unbalanced 'extDel'!
            printf("WARNING:get_str_segment: unbalanced '%c' encountered!\n",extDel);

            if (i==0) return NULL;  // we will not allow
            // **empty** unbalanced segments 'extDel'

            // if ('extDel' is unbalanced) it has to have at list one character!
            // It can be white space!
        }

        return (s);  // return pointer to next char after 'extDel'
        // ( It can be '\0')
        // if it is '\0' next pass will return 'NULL'!

    }
}

int parse_line_to_table(int firstDim, int secondDim, char *table, char * line, char separator)
{
    // Purpose:
    // Parse 'line' to 'table'
    // Function returns: number of segments
    // 'table' has to be passed from outside

    char* p;
    int   i;

    if(!table) return (-1);

    // parse segments to 'table':
    if(line)
    {
        p = line; // A necessary initialization!

        for(i=0; i<firstDim; i++)
        {
            p = get_str_segment( table+i*secondDim , p , separator );
            if(p==NULL) break;
        }
    }
    else
        return (-1);

    // debug only
    //    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) { printf(" i=%d %s",j, table+j*secondDim ); }
    //    printf("\n");

    return (i); // notice that i is post incremented
}

int main(void)
{
    char table[20][80];
    char *line =   "move this into \"tokens that I need\"";

    int ret = parse_line_to_table(20, 80, table, line, '\"');

    for(int i = 0; i < ret; i++ )
        printf("%s\n",table[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
move                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
this                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
into                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
tokens that I need
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Is it possible to store those tokens in an array for later access as well?

Comment: @Mike I think now you have all what you need. First example has been completely reworked. It is small and works great!

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  I'm going to dig into what you have written and see if I can get a better understanding of it.